# Ruby On Rails : Devise : Get email from 'resource.reset_password_token' in `Change your password` template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, devise, token, reset

`Scenario`: Show email in landing page when you click on password reset link
`Given` I am a user and I clicked on the password reset link inside my email
`Then` I am redirected to 'Change Password' page
`And` I see two password fields

`Expected` I also see the email of the user whose password is to be reset

`Problem`: How to get the email from only the `:reset_password_token` value?

Output from console when I `binding.pry` in the view `/views/devise/passwords/edit.html.erb`

```
[1] pry(#<#<Class:0x007fd4ec6f65f8>>)> resource
=> #<User id: nil, email: "", encrypted_password: "", reset_password_token: "Ba-9txxmmUMkU_xywypz", reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, customer_admin_id: nil, admin_id: nil, confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: nil, confirmation_sent_at: nil, organization_id: nil, status: nil, middle_name: nil, type: nil, cell_number: nil, phone_number: nil, extension: nil>
```

also When I invoke `User.find(5)` I see

```
 #<User id: 5, email: "recruiter_one+org_one@mysite.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$v7gYTdfoIZ9yCVIx3Xb5lOYVPly71NHtOc1mbWuHxZvt...", reset_password_token: "095a18fc2455c39e4838c322e3124d0052cf2cc0e86b7fe3486...", reset_password_sent_at: "2015-06-29 10:01:56", remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 10, current_sign_in_at: "2015-06-29 10:01:04", last_sign_in_at: "2015-06-29 09:35:56", current_sign_in_ip: "192.164.79.122", last_sign_in_ip: "192.164.79.122", created_at: "2015-06-12 05:06:50", updated_at: "2015-06-29 10:01:56", first_name: "Rec One Loc One", last_name: "Peter", customer_admin_id: nil, admin_id: nil, confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: "2015-06-12 05:13:49", confirmation_sent_at: "2015-06-12 05:06:50", organization_id: 3, status: "active", middle_name: "", type: nil, cell_number: "", phone_number: "1231232131", extension: "">
```

That is:

```
[4] pry(#<#<Class:0x007fd4ec6f65f8>>)> User.find(5).reset_password_token
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 5 LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
=> "095a18fc2455c39e4838c322e3124d0052cf2cc0e86b7fe3486f72a67c5a5315"
[5] pry(#<#<Class:0x007fd4ec6f65f8>>)>
```

`095a18fc2455c39e4838c322e3124d0052cf2cc0e86b7fe3486f72a67c5a5315` from database does not match with `Ba-9txxmmUMkU_xywypz` I get from `resource`

PS: I use `devise (3.2.4)`

Answer (score 2):

You should get digest from password_reset_token by

```
digiest = Devise.token_generator.digest(self, :reset_password_token, original_token)
```

where original_token is `Ba-9txxmmUMkU_xywypz`

Next, You can find resource by

```
user = User.find_by_reset_password_token(digiest)
```

Also, You should override password_controller#edit, and define `@email` variable

```
class PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
  # GET /resource/password/edit?reset_password_token=abcdef
  def edit
    digiest = Devise.token_generator.digest(resource_class, :reset_password_token, params[:reset_password_token])
    @email = resource_class.find_by_reset_password_token(digiest).email
    self.resource = resource_class.new
    set_minimum_password_length
    resource.reset_password_token = params[:reset_password_token]
  end
end
```

in routes.rb

```
devise_for :users,
         :controllers => {
           :passwords => 'passwords'
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

For the latest version of devise `(>= v3.3.0)`, you could simply use the method given by devise `with_reset_password_token(:token)`

```
User.with_reset_password_token('sxZo2fk8hux6hKyufpCx')
```

This will return the user if exists or returns nil.

You also would want to override the `edit` method of `Devise::PasswordsController`, or for the simplest use, keep the above code in a helper.

Comment: `User.with_reset_password_token(resource.reset_password_token)` generates the following error in console were I pry `undefined method 'with_reset_password_token' for #<Class:0x00000008b60d98>`

Comment: You must be using an older version of `devise` probably. There is such method for more recent version of `devise` https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/recoverable.rb#L117-L120